# Error In Maven Spring 3 Dynamic Application

Tags: java, maven, jsp, spring-mvc, spring-3

i am using `maven`, `spring 3` for `dynamic project`. I am getting error at `<bean name="/hello.cs" class="com.maven.controller.HelloController"/>` as `Multiple annotations found at this line:
    - Class 'com.maven.controller.HelloController'`

**Project Structure**

[image]

**Web.xml**

```
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
 "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >

<web-app>
  <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>hello</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>hello</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.cs</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

**Spring.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">


    <bean name="/hello.cs" class="com.maven.controller.HelloController"/>


    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/"/>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

**index.jsp**

```
<jsp:forward page="WEB-INF/jsp/home.jsp"></jsp:forward>
```

**home.jsp**

```
<form action="./hello.cs" method="post">
    <div>
        <div>
            User Name:<input type="text" name="name"/>
        </div>
        <div>
            Password: <input type="password" name="pass"/>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="submit" value="Login"/>
        </div>
        <div>
            <p style="color: red">${msg}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

**HelloController**

```
package com.maven.controller;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.Controller;

public class HelloController extends AbstractController{

    public ModelAndView handleRequest(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws Exception {

        String name = req.getParameter("name");
        String pwd = req.getParameter("pass");

        Map<String, String> m = new HashMap<String, String>();

        if(name.equalsIgnoreCase("xyz") && pwd.equalsIgnoreCase("123")){

            m.put("msg", "welcome mr. "+req.getParameter("name"));
            return new ModelAndView("success", m);
        } else {
            m.put("msg", "Invalid");
            return new ModelAndView("home");
        }
    }
}
```

**pom.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.javatpoint</groupId>
  <artifactId>CubeGeneratorWeb</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>CubeGeneratorWeb Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-webmvc -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/servlet-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
    </dependency>


  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <finalName>CubeGeneratorWeb</finalName>
  </build>
</project>
```

**Error:**
[image]

Comment: `<bean name="/hello.cs" class="com.maven.controller.HelloController"/>` -  `name="/hello.cs"` bean name like this seems unusual..

Comment: yes i know but can you please tell me how to solve this error in `class="com.maven.controller.HelloController"`

Comment: what happens when you compile the project? Above error that you have indicated is something eclipse ide related

Comment: i am using eclipse ide, i have run the code it throws `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.maven.controller.HelloController`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After lots of struggle i got the answer, i had error in spring.xml file. check the solutions.

i need to add below code only in spring.xml file.

```
<!DOCTYPE beans PUBLIC "-//SPRING//DTD BEAN 2.0//EN"
                "http://www.springframework.org/dtd/spring-beans-2.0.dtd">
```

previously i was using below code

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">
```

for above code i need to change `pom.xml` file, i mean need to add more dependency.

so this is my final spring.xml file for this question only.

spring.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE beans PUBLIC "-//SPRING//DTD BEAN 2.0//EN"
            "http://www.springframework.org/dtd/spring-beans-2.0.dtd">

<beans>
    <bean name="/hello.sa" class="com.maven.controller.HelloController"/>

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/"/>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: It says class **'com.maven.controller.HelloController'** not found.

I see that you have put your **com.maven.controller.HelloController.java** file under **src\main\resources** folder.

[image]

It should be under **src\main\java folder**. So the hierarchy should be like

```
src
|-main
   |-java
      |-com
        |-maven
           |-controller
              |-HelloController.java
```

The reason is the directory structure followed by maven detects java files only if it's placed  under this hierarchy **src\main\java**, if you are using default configuration.

Can you right click on project and go to **Properties > Java Build Path > Source** and check whether **src\main\java** entry is there in the build path list or not? If not add it and try again.

Comment: no it is not resolved , it is showing comiplation error as `Multiple annotations found at this line:
 - Class 'com.maven.controller.HelloController'` in spring.xml

Comment: Please see the edited post. structure should be like above.

Comment: i have follwed your steps but it is showing same error. is it need to change `class="com.maven.controller.HelloController"` ?

Comment: i am using eclipse ide, i have run the code it throws `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.maven.controller.HelloController`

Comment: can you clean and rebuild your project?

Comment: i have done clean and rebuild, but it is showing same error.

Comment: Oh...in that case I doubt I could provide any help. Sorry. It should work. There are always small things which create bigger problems. Anyways will see. In the mean time if you find a solution, do not forget to post it here. :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127184/discussion-between-sam-and-chirag-parmar).

Comment: hey check the solution, i had error in spring.xml file

Comment: Where is the solution?

Comment: check the solution now, i have modified my answer